# laravel 5.1 localization not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have some issue with the localization in laravel 5.1
I have inserted the various langs files in the main lang folder.
There, i have "en" folder and "ru" folder etc..

ex:

home.php:

```
return [
 'something' => 'something testing',
];
```

In the route i have this GET:

```
get('/gui/{lang}/{id}/{ver}/',['as' => 'gui', 'uses' => 'GuiController@home']);
```

but the langs didn't change.
if i change the route URL the text stays always in the "en" default lang.
some example:

http://domain.com/gui/en/1/home

http://domain.com/gui/ru/1/home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise you to read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization), because it seems to me you haven't done that.

On your `GuiController@home` you have to set your locale,

```
public function home($lang, $id, $ver){
    App::setLocale($lang)
    echo trans('home.something');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the `home.`-prefix.